# initialization of fsharp class field

Tags: xaml, f#, initialization

I have a class bound to a XAML file.
Upon the first call to it, the field selectedudl is = null.

Do you know why it is the case ?
I would have expected it to be = "" ..

```ml
type QuotesViewModel() =
    inherit ViewModelBase()
    let mutable histo = Array.empty
    let mutable selectedudl = ""

    member x.GetUnderlyings = seq { yield "one"; yield "two"}

    member x.SelectedUdl 
      with get() = selectedudl
      and set value = 
               selectedudl  <- value
               x.OnPropertyChanged <@ x.SelectedUdl @>
               x.OnPropertyChanged <@ x.SelectedGraph @>

    member x.SelectedGraph 
      with get() = 
               let graph  = asyncquotes.visualizehistoForUdl  selectedudl
               let host =  new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost()
               host.Child <- new ChartControl(graph, Dock = DockStyle.Fill)
               host
```

Comment: Hm, sounds like either something calls `x.SelectedUdl <- null` or else the constructor is not being called. You can add tracing to both to figure out.

Comment: indeed... can you post it as answer ?